# Making PySpark UDF access instance variable inside a Python Class

Tags: python, dataframe, class, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to apply a PySpark UDF to add a new column to a PySpark DataFrame inside a class. The Spark UDF has to be a static method in order to be used inside a class. The dummy example **Case 1** below works  fine.

The problem is that once the UDF is defined as static method, I cannot use any instance variable inside it. Hence, the **Case 2** does not work.

**Question:**
My question is not about why the Case 2 fails. I would like to know if there is any way to make the PySpark UDF access instance variable in the above example? I am aware of [this](https://csyhuang.github.io/2019/09/24/pyspark-could-not-serialize-object/?fbclid=IwAR16z05mSbX3NORbRxRGuNgSHeoSlwSuwdrnmkFCP4-2txGA3Mn1ydPxoA0) workaround where the UDF is defined **inside** the method calling the UDF (`calculate_new_marks()`) in this example. Looking for alternates.

---

**Case 1 (**This works!**):** Static Method UDF ***without*** using any instance variable. It simply adds 10 to every student's marks.

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField

class example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.students = [[f'student_{i}', np.random.randint(80)] for i in range(3)]
        self.increase = 10
    
    def create_spark_df(self):
        cSchema = StructType([StructField("Name", StringType())\
                             ,StructField("Marks", IntegerType())])
        return spark.createDataFrame(self.students, schema=cSchema)

    @staticmethod
    @udf(returnType=IntegerType())
    def add_ten_marks(marks):
        return marks + 10    
    
    def calculate_new_marks(self):
        df = self.create_spark_df()
        df = df.withColumn("New Marks", self.add_ten_marks(col("Marks")))
        return df

c = example()
c.calculate_new_marks().show()

+---------+-----+---------+
|     Name|Marks|New Marks|
+---------+-----+---------+
|student_0|    2|       12|
|student_1|   42|       52|
|student_2|   11|       21|
+---------+-----+---------+
```

---

**Case 2 (**This fails!**):** Static Method UDF ***with*** using any instance variable (`self.increase` here).

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField

class example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.students = [[f'student_{i}', np.random.randint(80)] for i in range(3)]
        self.increase = 10
    
    def create_spark_df(self):
        cSchema = StructType([StructField("Name", StringType())\
                             ,StructField("Marks", IntegerType())])
        return spark.createDataFrame(self.students, schema=cSchema)

    @staticmethod
    @udf(returnType=IntegerType())
    def add_ten_marks(marks):
        return marks + self.increase # <--- constant replaced by instance variable. Problematic Line!!!
    
    def calculate_new_marks(self):
        df = self.create_spark_df()
        df = df.withColumn("New Marks", self.add_ten_marks(col("Marks")))
        return df

c = example()
c.calculate_new_marks().show()

>>> PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'NameError: name 'self' is not defined'
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Spark UDF is meant to be self contained and is serialized and executed on the worker and not on the driver thats why it is meant to be static.
So, you can try the below alternative,

You can may be pass the variable increase to the udf as an argument like below.

---

```
@staticmethod
@udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def add_ten_marks(marks, increase):
    return marks + increase
```

---

```
df = df.withColumn("New Marks", self.add_ten_marks(col("Marks"), lit(self.increase)))
```

---

Comment: This works perfectly fine. The `lit( )` here is necessary. One can't just pass variables. Thanks!